# vue js returned value gives undefined error

Tags: vue.js

i want to check the returned value of $http.get() but i get undefined value. Here is my vue js code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#permissionMgt',
    data: {
        permissionID: []

    },

methods:{
fetchPermissionDetail: function (id) {
            this.$http.get('../api/getComplaintPermission/' + id, function (data) {

                    this.permissionID = data.permissionID; //permissionID is a data field of the database
                    alert(this.permissionID); //*****this alert is giving me undefined value

            });
        },

}
    });
```

Can you tell me thats the problem here?.. btw $http.get() is properly fetching all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what type is the `data` returned from the server. If @Raj's solution didn't resolve your issue then probably `permissionID` is not present in the `data` that is returned.

Do a `colsole.log(data)` and check whether `data` is an `object` or an `array` of `objects`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Its a common js error. Make the following changes and it will work.

```
fetchPermissionDetail: function (id) {

        var self = this; //add this line
        this.$http.get('../api/getComplaintPermission/' + id, function (data) {

                self.permissionID = data.permissionID; //replace "this" with "self"


            });
        },

}
```

the reason is `this` points to `window` inside the anonymous function `function()`

This is a well known js problem. If you are using es2015 you can use arrow syntax (`() => { /*code*/ }`) syntax which sets `this` correctly

Comment: Hi Raj, thanks but i am still getting the same undefined issue.

Comment: can you update your code? or if possible, provide a jsfiddle?